# Finding maximum difference between each string in an list

Tags: python, string, algorithm, performance

This was an interview question given to me:

> Given a list of n strings with length l which at any given index can contain either the character 'a' or 'b', how would I go about figuring out the maximum difference (meaning the amount of characters that differ at each index) for each n string in the lowest possible time complexity.
>
> An example of this would be ["abaab", "abbbb","babba"]
>
> The output would be [5, 3, 5] as the difference between the first and third strings is 5 (none of the characters are the same), so the maximum difference between string 1 and any other string is 5. Similarly, the difference between string 2 and string 3 is 3, which is greater than the difference between string 2 and 1. And the difference between string 3 and string 1 is 5.
>
> The limit for l is 20

I tried the following code (where l and n are named accordingly and strings is the list of strings). The variables in this code are those of the sample case, but I would like a generalized solution.

```
n = 3
l = 5
abmap = {}
strings = ["abaab", "abbbb","babba"]

for i in range(l):
    abmap[i] = {"a": [], "b": []}

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(l):
        if strings[i][j] == "a":
            abmap[j]["a"].append(i)

        else:
            abmap[j]["b"].append(i)

for string in strings:
    differences = n * [0]
    for i in range(l):
        if string[i] == "a":
            for index in abmap[i]["b"]:
                differences[index] += 1

        else:
            for index in abmap[i]["a"]:
                differences[index] += 1

    print(max(differences))
```

However, this solution is O(n<sup>2</sup>·l). The interviewer asked me to optimize it further (such as to O(l·n·log(n)). How can I accomplish this?

The time limit for this is 15 seconds, and n is less than 100000.

Comment: Did they say O(lnlog(n)) or is that your guess?

Comment: And did they provide any limits, particularly for l?

Comment: That is my guess, a solution in O(ln) would be much appreciated as well but I guess O(lnlog(n)) is more attainable and probably desired by the interviewer.

Comment: They provided that the limit for l is 20. I'm sorry for not including that in the question I will edit now.

Comment: In that case: Did they actually ask for a better complexity class than that, or just to optimize it?

Comment: They asked for a better complexity case than what I have currently.

Comment: in your example the difference between the first and third strings is 4 (4th character is `b` in both).

Comment: Sorry for the issues with the code and sample case, @bn_ln I changed the sample case to the correct one, and Kelly Bundy I have added working code for the sample case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my earlier answer (not viable anymore now with the limits), I convert each string to an L-bit number. They're a subset of the 2<sup>L</sup> ≤ 2<sup>20</sup> possible L-bit numbers. Think of it as a graph of 2<sup>L</sup> nodes, there's an edge between two nodes if they differ by exactly one bit, and the input numbers are a subset of those nodes.

Now... for any input number, what is the most *far away* input number? We can solve that by instead looking at the *inverted* number (all L bits flipped, i.e., distance L away) and asking what is the *closest* input number to that. So we run a parallel BFS (breadth-first search) from the input numbers. We mark them as having distance 0. Then we mark all numbers one bit change away with distance 2. Then mark all numbers one further bit change away with distance 2. And so on. At the end, for each input number, we look at the distance of the inverted number, and subtract that from L.

Benchmark results, worst case takes ~3 seconds, well under the 15 seconds limit:

```
n=1000 L=20:
 0.14 s  solution1
 2.63 s  solution2

n=10000 L=20:
15.01 s  solution1
 3.01 s  solution2

n=100000 L=20:
 3.47 s  solution2
```

Full code (solution1 is my old, solution2 is the one I presented above):

```py
def solution1(strings):
    table = str.maketrans('ab', '01')
    numbers = [
        int(s.translate(table), 2)
        for s in strings
    ]
    return [
        max((x ^ y).bit_count() for y in numbers)
        for x in numbers
    ]

def solution2(strings):
    table = str.maketrans('ab', '01')
    numbers = [
        int(s.translate(table), 2)
        for s in strings
    ]
    L = len(strings[0])
    bits = [2**i for i in range(L)]
    dist = [None] * 2**L
    for x in numbers:
        dist[x] = 0
    horizon = numbers
    d = 1
    while horizon:
        horizon = [
            y
            for x in horizon
            for bit in bits
            for y in [x ^ bit]
            if dist[y] is None
            for dist[y] in [d]
        ]
        d += 1
    return [L - dist[~x] for x in numbers]

funcs = solution1, solution2

import random
from time import time

# Generate random input
def gen(n, L):
    return [
        ''.join(random.choices('ab', k=L))
        for _ in range(n)
    ]

# Correctness
for _ in range(100):
    strings = gen(100, 10)
    expect = funcs[0](strings)
    for f in funcs:
        result = f(strings)
        assert result == expect

# Speed
def test(n, L, funcs):
    print(f'{n=} {L=}:')

    for _ in range(1):
        strings = gen(n, L)
        expect = None
        for f in funcs:
            t = time()
            result = f(strings)
            print(f'{time()-t:5.2f} s ', f.__name__)
            if expect is None:
                result = expect
            else:
                assert result == expect
            del result
    print()

test(1000, 20, [solution1, solution2])
test(10000, 20, [solution1, solution2])
test(100000, 20, [solution2])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=zVW9rpswFN468BSW7gCkBEGkSlWkTB26oC4dI4pIOCTuBRvZRk16lb5Il7u0Yx-oT9NjY_6S3KpjLSXCPt_5-_wd-P6zOasjZ8_PP1pVLt_-fvWrgJJIXrWKchZ7UgnKDtJfOwSXyncVkA3B07DOH0GJnEnPzXduQNwodn2DYm29AyERtzV7vShTngwNvsoVeCaSH5CVP0BKLohEILE5jSE1_wJUK9gkXJ2fPO9EPpGzH-6oyva8xQS-iXHWMWwN8-inicVGd6btrv6TdhOMVQHrq9lGaeeGnZo0q8WCGn-q_THJAbzE73wLKpXGfOAMUrIgiE2cewSsh0q0y_aUoldkzo5c0K-c4X7KVYH72Dx9OVKkxaLGMKPbyINe59luKMPCb4zYpDbrXm9s5mq3-t7RnM7MtOz6OKeESqK7v_Ee7BijGL3Hp4K87nvsFZeQZef3DQm6phDlU7Zsr-9kmJhgVJPj0LrhQukbKnjtlILXRNEaiD3Xz47zQN4DA4EysUDM0LTKKPOAKmABSawgb-bAdcPPnDKvcwz3R0730Ev0cZP4c71lo16Y30_AA3nHhYC9YiClcwWLo8jmtmLEXnVReB6QOOqCwKlBd7QYNlCuwxwNyit1SGMeBSNAtpVxm-P1yqUEzZyFbGwOXe3HBqAw7CiQytATdKFtpY3Q41e6T2xzIU_J5rLGSXXucBD7YzHz9gzng23obyarl9rSS4P17Xr-7PhvHc8q73yXav0mXJUXfE_gdZZhlrG8hizzr5VvC7TCn5cyy2tZnNqgknc8XuJ_iimgsoAJ7ci0uRYUCCpkhb_tvdnAN9oA-2fcNRCt3WfLfr36r9gf)

Answer (score 1):

(With the now added limits for n and time, this is no longer viable. See my newer answer instead.)

The limit 20 for L (renamed for readability) suggests that they wanted you to convert each string to an L-bit number, and then compute the difference of two of them by xoring them and asking for the popcount, to have O(1) for each difference and thus O(nL+n²) overall.

```py
strings = ["abaab", "abbbb", "babba"]

table = str.maketrans('ab', '01')
numbers = [int(s.translate(table), 2)
           for s in strings]

for x in numbers:
    print(max((x ^ y).bit_count()
              for y in numbers))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9BCsIwEEX3PcXQTRKoRV2J4ElEZSKpBtu0JFNoz-KmG72TS29iEiPqrD6fP2_mX-_dSOfWTNOtp2q2ejwdWW1ODjawzVEiyrwAL_wEIb3CfJdlhLJWPuTjZYMXRRaN4wwlK4DNF0xkpm-kshGkDXFXxkiNpHhcFgUsRQbfqVoLDrSB9IK_EqwhWAm2jvnOBmCDA-cD7GEUpdR0OLa9d_-ICTr-EIR4F019P71f)

Comment: Thank you for the response! However there are barely any constraints on n, and a solution where the coefficient of n is logn instead of n is what I think was expected.

Comment: What do you mean with "barely any"? What constraints are there on n?

Comment: @ArjunSenthil Added code now.

Comment: n is a number less than 10000, and a solution involving n^2 would probably time out. Is there a way to optimize this to lnlog(n)?

Comment: @ArjunSenthil Hmm, an actual limit on n, and timing out. That seems unusual for an interview. What was the time limit? I don't see a better solution yet, I'll think about it.

Comment: The time limit on the problem was 15 seconds and a solution in python. One of the testcases had n = 9950.

Comment: @ArjunSenthil I just tried it with 10000 strings of length 20 and it took 14.8 seconds. And that was on the ATO website, which is not the fastest. And perhaps it could be sped up by not computing every difference twice. Is that online somewhere for actual testing? I also have an idea for O(n²L) that might be faster, lol.

Comment: @ArjunSenthil And if lnlog(n) were intended, I don't think they'd use such a large time limit.

Comment: Sorry lol, I messed up. The n limit was 100000, and the testcase I was talking about had n = 99500.

Comment: @ArjunSenthil Ok, that's a different beast then. Please put these limits into the question. And what about this being online for testing?

Comment: The problem was not online for testing, however it was administered in a testing center earlier today for an hour. I will add the n limit to the problem.